# Let $R$, $S$ be rings with identity and $f: R\to S$ a homomorphism. Is there a name for the this subset of the units of $R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $U(R)$ be the set of units in $R$ (the elements that have multiplicative inverses), and consider the subset $\{r\in U(R): f(r) = 1\}$. That is, the set of elements of $U(R)$ that are mapped to the *multiplicative* identity of $S$. This is analogous to the kernel of $f$, but clearly isn't a subring since if $f(r)=f(s)=1$ then $f(r+s) = f(r)+f(s)=1+1\ne1$. It seems to be a subgroup under multiplication though, since $f(rs) = f(r)f(s) = 1\cdot 1=1$, and $f(r^{-1}) = f(r)^{-1}=1^{-1}=1$. Is there a name or any other interesting properties of this subset (subgroup) of $U(R)$?

My apologies if this question has been asked before; since I don't have a name for it, I wouldn't know what to search for.

Comment: I think $1 + \text{ker}(f)$ may be the best you'll get for a name.

Comment: @nbritten That name being motivated by this set being equal to $\{1 + r : f(r) = 0\}$?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken it should be the coset of ker$(f)$ containing $1$ in $R$, intersected with the units of $R$ if we require it to contain only units.

Comment: Yes, it is important that it contains only units so that it is a subgroup under multiplication. In that case it is just a coset of $\ker f$, nothing too interesting. Oh well, was just curious. You can write that as an answer, perhaps with some elaboration, and I will accept it.

Comment: @Math1000 Might as well leave it unanswered for a bit, somebody else might have seen something similar.

Comment: Note that $f$ induces a group homomorphism $U(R)\to U(S)$, since $f$ is asumed to take $1_R$ to $1_S$. So your set is the kernel of this induced homomorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every unital morphism between rings $f\colon R\to S$ induces a multiplicative group homomorphism, which we might denote $U(f)\colon U(R)\to U(S)$. Your set is $\mathrm{ker}(U(f))$.

---

Note that there is a functor from the category of rings with unity and unital morphisms (morphisms that must send the multiplicative identity to the multiplicative identity) to the category of groups, $U\colon \mathscr{R}ing^1\to\mathscr{G}roup$, defined by mapping a ring $R$ to its unit group $U(R)$, and a morphism $f\colon R\to S$ to the restriction $U(f)=f|_{U(R)}$. This is a functor, since 
$$\begin{align*}
U(\mathrm{id}_{R}) &= \mathrm{id}_{U(R)}\\
U(g\circ f) &= (g\circ f)|_{U(R)} = g|_{U(S)}\circ f|_{U(R)} = U(g)\circ U(f).
\end{align*}$$
Your set can also be seen as the image of the kernel under the functor.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "unital morphism?" Is that just a homomorphism on the set of units of $R$?

Comment: @Math1000: Depending on your definition of “ring”, you may or may not require homomorphisms $R\to S$ to send $1_R$ to $1_S$ (even when they both exist; for example, under some situations, you may want $R\hookrightarrow R\times R$ via $r\mapsto (r,0)$ to be a morphism); a unital morphism is one that sends $1_R$ to $1_S$.

Comment: Hmm, I am interested here in the unital morphism then. I will accept your answer as that appears to be the most structure we can impose on this set. Thank you.